# %defattr behaviour change between rpm 4.7.2 and 4.9.1?

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Is it permissible to use `%defattr` multiple times in spec file? Under Ubuntu 10 (rpm version 4.7.1), the following definition would result in 777 permissions applied to */var/log/testdir2*.

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%dir /var/log/testdir1
%defattr(777,root,root,-)
%dir /var/log/testdir2
%dir %attr(777,root,root) /var/log/testdir3
```

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04.1 (x86_64RPM version 4.9.1.1), regenerating the rpm with the same spec file and deploying to the same target machine resulted in */var/log/testdir2* having permissions 755. I have to change the spec file to define `%attr` as in */var/log/testdir3* above in order to get the desired permissions.

The spec file had a `%defattr` definition followed by the set of files having those permissions, then another `%defattr` definition followed by the set of files with those permissions.  Is that not allowed?  Or is there a difference between how directories and files are treated with regard to permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%defattr` is usually used to set the default attributes for files/directories, so using it multiple times seems odd to me. First let's look at the `%defattr` values: `%defattr(file perms, user, group, dir perms)`. So probably the /var/log/testdir3 directory has permissions of 755 in your tarball since you're not setting the directory permissions, it's just inheriting them.

Try something like this:

```
%files
%defattr(755,root,root,777)
%dir /var/log/testdir1
%dir /var/log/testdir2
%dir /var/log/testdir3
```

Using what I have above, it will set the directories to 777, and then set all files that you list to 755 because it's inheriting the default values (both with ownership of root.root).

I'm still a bit confused as to why you're setting permissions on a log dir to 777, as when you declare the %dir it only sets the directory permissions. Are you not trying to set the files to something? If you need a specific directory with different permissions you should be using the `%attr` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right, setting the 4th param, dir permissions, is doing what I want. I have groups of directories (containing no files) with differing permissions. Each group is prefixed by a different %defattr setting. The behaviour of my rpm changed after a recent os upgrade (new version of rpmbuild), but it seems I may not have been using %defattr quite right to begin with. Thanks.